# why can't orderby desc and asc work? in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, datatables

example image data :[image: []]

when the js responds, the data has already been ordered by
example image response js :[image: []]

example controller and query :

```
$query = Verifikasi_tte::join('surat_ttes', 'surat_ttes.id', '=', 'verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id')
                 ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.user_id')
                 ->join('jenis_surat_ttes', 'jenis_surat_ttes.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.jenis_surat_tte_id')
                 ->select('surat_ttes.id','surat_ttes.klasifikasi','surat_ttes.no_surat','surat_ttes.tgl_surat','surat_ttes.created_at',
                 'jenis_surat_ttes.nama_jenis_surat','users.name','verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id','verifikasi_ttes.status')
                 ->orderBy('surat_ttes.id','DESC')->get();
          return Datatables::of($query)
```

example view in ajax datables :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (e) {
            $('#data-table').DataTable({
            pageLength: 10,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            stateSave: true,
            ajax: "{{ url ('/verifikasi/data') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'nama_jenis_surat', name: 'nama_jenis_surat'},
                {data: 'no_surat', name: 'no_surat'},
                {data: 'dates', name: 'dates'},
                {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

is there something wrong with my controller?

Comment: remove ->get() direct inject $query Datatables::of($query)

Comment: Try manually writing full sql query in variable and then passing it in `Datatables::of($query)`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `get()` function in the controller.

```
$query = Verifikasi_tte::join('surat_ttes', 'surat_ttes.id', '=', 'verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id')
                 ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.user_id')
                 ->join('jenis_surat_ttes', 'jenis_surat_ttes.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.jenis_surat_tte_id')
                 ->select('surat_ttes.id','surat_ttes.klasifikasi','surat_ttes.no_surat','surat_ttes.tgl_surat','surat_ttes.created_at',
                 'jenis_surat_ttes.nama_jenis_surat','users.name','verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id','verifikasi_ttes.status', 'verifikasi_ttes.nama_jenis_surat')
                 ->orderBy('surat_ttes.id','DESC')
          return Datatables::of($query)
```

This happens because the Datatables plugin wants a eloquent query object to do the sorting and searching features.

Also, the Table definition of your JS code should match the table column names correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (e) {
            $('#data-table').DataTable({
            pageLength: 10,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            stateSave: true,
            ajax: "{{ url ('/verifikasi/data') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'verifikasi_ttes.nama_jenis_surat', name: 'verifikasi_ttes.nama_jenis_surat'},
                {data: 'no_surat', name: 'no_surat'},
                {data: 'dates', name: 'dates'},
                {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if I don't use get, there is an error for searching the datatables?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I've written in the comments about the error and the problem, please help me sir

Answer (score 0):

because I use soft delete, so if to use the query builder it might not be possible for soft delete but eloquent, now here I combine eloquent with query builder, and I have tried not to use get() it works but to search data in the datatables package yajra there was an error in the form of the column field from the join query was not found

example image error search : [image]

if example not use get() :

```
$query = Verifikasi_tte::join('surat_ttes', 'surat_ttes.id', '=', 'verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id')
                 ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.user_id')
                 ->join('jenis_surat_ttes', 'jenis_surat_ttes.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.jenis_surat_tte_id')
                 ->select('surat_ttes.id','surat_ttes.klasifikasi','surat_ttes.no_surat','surat_ttes.tgl_surat','surat_ttes.created_at',
                 'jenis_surat_ttes.nama_jenis_surat','users.name','verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id','verifikasi_ttes.status')
                 ->orderBy('surat_ttes.id','DESC')
          return Datatables::of($query)
```

when I create a column in the form of a function, the return result of the query variable :

```
$query = Verifikasi_tte::join('surat_ttes', 'surat_ttes.id', '=', 'verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id')
                 ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.user_id')
                 ->join('jenis_surat_ttes', 'jenis_surat_ttes.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.jenis_surat_tte_id')
                 ->select('surat_ttes.id','surat_ttes.klasifikasi','surat_ttes.no_surat','surat_ttes.tgl_surat','surat_ttes.created_at',
                 'jenis_surat_ttes.nama_jenis_surat','users.name','verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id','verifikasi_ttes.status')
                 ->orderBy('surat_ttes.id','DESC');
          return Datatables::of($query)
        ->addColumn('dates', function ($query) {
          $dates = Carbon::parse($query->created_at)->translatedFormat('l, d F Y');
          return $dates;
        })
        ->addColumn('name', function ($query) {
          $name = $query->name;
          return $name;
        })
        ->addColumn('nama_jenis_surat', function ($query) {
          $nama_surat = $query->nama_jenis_surat;
          return $nama_surat;
        })
        ->addColumn('no_surat', function ($query) {
          $no_surat = $query->no_surat;
          return $no_surat;
        })
```

this method works and no error message appears in the column datatables, but what happens is that the search for query results in the datatables doesn't work .., is there anything to add to the ajax datatables yajra?, or change the controller in the query totally?

example image search datatables not working : [image]

Comment: You don't need to add the column manually if you add it to the `select` clause. Also, you have to define the column name correctly in the JS definition as well.

Comment: You can check the updated answer below.